# Using collapse/accordian for showing items in grid using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a grid of 3 by 3 items which are basically images. When a user clicks any one of them, I want to show an explanation for that item and when the user clicks something else, I want to collapse this item explanation and show the explanation of the item which is clicked.
I have used accordian for listing panels but in this case I need to do it for a grid of items. 
An example of what I am trying is here,

http://jsfiddle.net/viggy_prabhu/ychw6/

```
<div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#collapseOne">
```

Issues in it:
1) When I click any of the 9, all other items should be collapsed state.
2) The explanation should come in full row instead of just in the column.

Comment: I'm sure you can expand upon this, but i added in some jquery in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ychw6/2/

If you open the first collapsable group 2 item and then open the first collapsable group one item, you'll see the group 2 one will hide.

as for the explanation coming in a full row, the width of your columns are 33.3%, so the explanation will also be 33.3%, that should give you a head start. Currently at work so I cant really do much more than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think bootstrap default collapse won't easily work for you problem, and I think it's easier to create your own collapse block to do what you want. Look at this fiddle, it should do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/tRW9b/

I removed the third row but it's almost the same as first and second row, and I remove most CSS but you can add whatever you want, I just wanted a simple DOM.

The idea is to have for each row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><a>First button</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><a>Second button</a></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"><a>Third button</a></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="row collapse"><a>First description</a></div>
    <div class="row collapse"><a>Second description</a></div>
    <div class="row collapse"><a>Third description</a></div>
</div>
```

Then you just add a `on('click', ...)` on your link (in the fiddle, I add callback on every link, but you just need to modify a bit the JS code to change that), then in callback you have several cases:

- The target of your link is visible => You only need to hide it (using `slideUp`, you can use something else like `fadeOut`)
- The target of your link is not visible, but there is a visible target on same row => You first add the visible target, then you show your target: `visible.slideUp(function () { target.slideDown() });`
- The target of your link is not visible, but there is a target visible on another row => You hide the visible target and show your target simultaneously: `visible.slideUp() ; target.slideDown() ;`

The last case also works if there is no other target visible since the `.filter(':visible')` will return an empty list.